# Differential of the Integral of a two variables function

Tags: integration, differential

I have trouble to understand how to understand the equality  between the 2 terms equation (1)

\begin{equation}
  f: \mathbb{R^+} \times \mathbb{R}  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  f \in \mathbb{C}^{1,1}  
\end{equation}

(1)

\begin{equation}
  d(\int_{0}^{t} \frac{\partial}{\partial s} f(s,x) ds) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(t,x) dt
\end{equation}

This result comes from the two differents way to present Ito's Lemma:

\begin{equation}
f(t,X_t) = f(0,X_0) + \int_{0}^{t} \frac{\partial f}{\partial s}(s,X_s) ds + \int_{0}^{t} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(s,X_s) dX_s + \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(s,X_s) d[X]_s
\end{equation}

Which can be differentiate in:

\begin{equation} df(t,X_t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t,X_t) dt + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,X_t) dX_t + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(t,X_t) d[X]_t
\end{equation}

I find a different result for equation (1) because I have always learnt that:

\begin{equation}
df(x,y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) dy
\end{equation}

Applying this to (1) I find:

\begin{equation}
  d(\int_{0}^{t} \frac{\partial}{\partial s} f(s,x) ds) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(t,x) dt
\end{equation}
$\iff$
\begin{equation}
  d(\int_{0}^{t} \frac{\partial}{\partial s} f(s,x) ds) = d( f(t,x) - f(0,x))
\end{equation}

Admitting that $f(0,x) = 0$ we obtain:

\begin{equation}
df(t,x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t,x) dt + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,x) dx
\end{equation}

Which is different to equation (1). I don't understand why we seem to be able to remove \begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,x) dx
\end{equation}

I feel like this is something basic but I'm really struggling to understand, can anyone help?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The ant-derivative, with  respect to $s$, of $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}f(x,s)$ is $f(s,x)$. Thus the integral is $f(t,x)-f(0,x)$ . $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(f(t,x)-f(0,x))=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(f(t,x))$$ $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f(t,x)-f(0,x))=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f(t,x))-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(f(0,t))$$

Comment: I don't understand how your answer justify the fact that:

\begin{equation}
  d(\int_{0}^{t} \frac{\partial}{\partial s} f(s,x) ds) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(t,x) dt
\end{equation}

and not:

\begin{equation}
  d(\int_{0}^{t} \frac{\partial}{\partial s} f(s,x) ds) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(t,x) dt + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(t,x) dx
\end{equation}

Comment: @Sebos75001I don't like the "d" symbolism but if you insist on using it, $$d(\text{thing}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\text{(thing)}dt+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\text{(thing)}dx$$